# Pass prop to different page in Next JS/ React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to pass props to a new page in Next JS.

I'm mapping through an array, each item should link to a page where I can use data from the array as props:

```
 {mentors.map((mentor) => (
            <Link href="/developers/developer">
              <div
                key="name"
                className="flex flex-col text-green-50 bg-gray-800 rounded-md p-6 gap-3 border border-gray-800 hover:border-gray-700 cursor-pointer"
              >
                <div className="flex justify-between items-center ">
                  <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <img src={mentor.pic} className="rounded-full w-10" />{" "}
                    {mentor.name}
                  </div>
                  {mentor.timeZone}
                </div>
                <p className="text-gray-300">
                  I am a full-stack dev with over 8 years experience in
                  making software and web-apps.
                </p>
                <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                  Can teach:
                  {mentor.languages.map((language) => (
                    <p
                      key={language}
                      className="px-3 py-1  bg-gray-900 rounded-full max-w-max text-sm"
                    >
                      {language}
                    </p>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
```

This is the page:

```
export default function DeveloperPage({ name, picture }) {
  return (
    <>
    {name}
    <img src={picture}/> </>)}
```

I need to pass that {name} and {picture} prop from the item in the array to the new page.
What's the most elegant way to do it in Next?

Thanks!

Comment: is the name and picture was from the mentor props? something like `mentor.name` and `metor.picture` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it trough URL query

Like this

```js
<Link href={`/developers/developer?name=${mentor.name}&picture=${mentor.picture}`}>
```

and you can use `useRouter` on your `DeveloperPage` to get its values

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function DeveloperPage() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const {name, picture} = router.query // <-- passed datas are in here

  return (
    <>
        {name}
        <img src={picture}/> 
    </>
  )
}
```